# c++ Calling a constructor for a class

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, undefined-reference

I'm new to the bigger concepts of C++ and am attempting to write a small program to test the behaviors of constructors and deconstructors. However I cannot seem to get the program to compile because of silly errors about undefined references to myClass::myClass or not being able to call a constructor directly.

My code is as such:

myClass.h:

```
#pragma once

class myClass{

int x;

public:
    myClass(int n_x);

    myClass();

    ~myClass();
};
```

myClass.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "myClass.h"

myClass(int n_x)
:x(n_x)
{
// constructor
std::cout << "A myClass object was created! And x == " << x << "!" << std::endl;
}

myClass()
:x(10)
{
// default constructor
std::cout << "A myClass object was created! And x == " << x << "!" << std::endl;
}

~myClass()
{
// deconstructor
std::cout << "A myClass object was destroyed!" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myClass.h"

using namespace std;

void func();
myClass* func2();

int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

myClass obj1;

func();

myClass* obj2 = func2();

delete obj2;

cout << "Goodbye world!" << endl;

return 0;
}

void func()
{
myClass obj1 = myClass(15);
}

myClass* func2()
{
myClass* obj1 = new myClass(5); // using the new operator to allocate memory in free space (the heap)

return obj1;
}
```

Am I obviously doing something wrong? Coming from a Java background here.

====EDIT====
Found out what was wrong. Now I feel dumb. 
For whatever reason the myClass.h and myClass.cpp files were created and in the directory of my project but not shown in the project tree in code::blocks. Once I added the files to the project it compiled successfully.

Thank you for your time and answers. Even though my issue was not really related to my code I still learned some things from your replies.

Comment: Those "silly errors" tell you exactly what the problem is. Including them would make it much easier for people to help you!

Comment: I can't remember encountering a "Cannot call a constructor directly" error anywhere. Not that it's impossible: compilers do sometimes issue nonsense diagnostics. Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Huh, I tried changing my code back to 'myClass obj1 = myClass();' to get the Cannot call a constructor error again and couldn't get it to come up. Now I'm only getting "Undefined reference to 'myClass::myClass()' and similar erros for the overloaded constructor and destructor where ever the objects are being created or going out of scope. I changed my myClass.cpp file to properly use the scope resolution operator for the methods (so myClass::myClass() instead of just myClass()) but I still get the undefined reference error.

Comment: BTW, on top of posting the error, which would help, also always post your tool chain. There actually are bugs with things like compilers some times, some in VC in the past were actually pretty insidious and could let through code that was miles off the actual C++ standard.

Comment: Your code in `myClass.cpp` is illegal. Your compiler should be saying something about it. If not, then perhaps you are not even compiling `myClass.cpp` .

Comment: New to c++ compilers here and using Code::Blocks currently, how do I find my tool chain? Sorry for being so green, following along a book I'm reading and new to c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the answer you already got about implementing things in their right name space, and since you seem to want to know more about constructor/destructor in first place:

When you see

```
myClass* whatever = new myClass();
```

work it's because the new operator is the one handing a pointer back that can be cast to a pointer of type myClass.

I don't know any Java, but having reviewed C++ code by people who do I'm under the impression there might be something like explicit constructors Java programmers might be used to. In C++ constructors are more implicitly handled, E.G. chains of constructors on subclassing don't need (don't even support) explicit invocation, they are automatically called up the chain of inheritance.

Long story short, don't treat constructors and destructors like normal function like methods to implement, treat them like mandatory, implicitly managed resource handlers.

Comment: re "Your constructor doesn't return an object of type myClass, a compiler won't be able to resolve that.", not sure what you're trying to say here, like what's the "that", but it sounds like a misunderstanding.

Comment: True, edited that. Having trouble articulating what I want to get across.

Comment: Oh, but "it can't be called like some named function expected to return a constructed instance of your class", it *can* be called that way. That's why I'd be interested to see the OP's alleged error diagnostic.

Comment: Yeah MyClass whatever = MyClass() is valid, I was trying to get something else across but failing at it. I've removed that paragraph. I would delete the answer actually as it seems more confusing than anything, but as it's been accepted I can't delete it any longer.

Answer (score 1):

In "myClass.cpp", you need to fully qualify the names of the functions when you define them.  I.e.

```
myClass::myClass(int n_x): x(n_x) {
//...
}
```

The compiler doesn't know that you're defining member functions of `myClass` without the full qualification.  As far as it's concerned, you could be defining some free function named `myClass`.

Also, you need to include `<iostream>` in order to use `std::cout`.